# Gson parse array

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, gson, retrofit

I get a response which it could be one of two

```
"data": [
{
  "uuid": ".......",
  "error": true,
  "code": 142,
  "text": "Invalid uuid"
}
]
```

or

```
"data": {
"download_url": "http://....."
 }
```

in order to parse it in my app i get it with retrofit as an object

```
public class downloadFileResponse extends generalStatusResponse {
Object data;

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

and try to parse it  like this

```
if (response.getStatus().getCode().equals("136")) {
                    String res = new Gson().toJson(response.getData());
                    try {
                        JSONObject t = new JSONObject(res);
                        Log.v("this", "r- " + t.getString("download_url"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        List<downloadFileDataErrorFields> error = new Gson().fromJson(response.getData().toString(), new TypeToken<List<downloadFileDataErrorFields>>() { }.getType());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

and my downloadFileDataErrorFields object is this

```
public class downloadFileDataErrorFields {
String uuid;
String error;
String code;
String text;

public downloadFileDataErrorFields() {
}

public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
}
```

the second response with just the download_url it works fine, but when i try to parse the first one with the errors i get this

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 87 path $[0].text
```

in this column there is a space in the "Invalid uuid" string.

Anyone know how to fix this? or to properly parse the different types of responses?

Thank you

Comment: The first json is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your first JSON example is not a json list but an json object with list as a child.

You should create a new class representing that JSON structure, like this:

```
public class DownloadFileDataError {

private downloadFileDataErrorFields data;

public DownloadFileDataError() {
}

public String getFields() {
    return data;
}   

}
```

Then deserialize it like this:

```
DownloadFileDataError error = new Gson().fromJson(response.getData().toString());
```